# pageCurl and pageUncurl API usage in app

Tags: iphone, animation, catransition

I know this question was asked here many times before but I am still not sure whether apple will reject the app if I used "pageCurl" and "pageUncurl" animation types.

I found some very old links mentioning their app got rejected but it was before SDK 3.2 and I also come to know that in SDK 3.2 apple allowed this animation.

I think based on research apple might not reject it but I am looking for someone who can confirm this based on facts.

```
 CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:0.45f];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
if (!curled){
    animation.type = @"pageCurl";
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.endProgress = 0.58;
} else {
    animation.type = @"pageUnCurl";
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
    animation.startProgress = 0.42;
}

[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[[mCurlPage layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageFlipAnimation"];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a pretty old post, but we have actually had an app, in the Store for some months now, which uses this animation.

It seems that Apple might allow it even though it is not officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

after lot of googling I have dropped the plan to use pageCurl and pageUncurl API in my iphone app since there is no app which have this API and is approved in app store. hopefully apple will enable this API in future.